# What is the limit to add an application to the QuickBooks Web Connector?

Tags: c#, web-services, quickbooks

I would like to know that how many number of application can we add to QuickBooks Web Connector?

Currently, I have added 12 different qwc files for 4 different company files. Each qwc file is for different task and there are more tasks to come for newer company files and existing as well.

Shall I merge tasks into one to reduce the number of qwc files in web connector?

I separated each task because, suppose I got error while pushing customer then web connector stops execution and I was not able to push invoices and other stuff through same qwc file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I currently have around 60 applications added (60 different company file) and it seems to be working great so far. I plan on adding some more to see how much the Web Connector can handle - as a stress test.

I would recommend you to have one application per quickbooks file. That's how I've set it up. It's easier to manage, in my opinion.

Here are a few things that might help:

- Reduce the `Auto-Run` frequency so it runs more often
- Store the timestamp for each task (or Query Action) once it is successfully completed/processed
- Send email or some kind of notification when the run fails, so that you can look into it and fix it

Comment: Thank you so much @avi.